# syntax error at or near "AS"

Tags: postgresql, select, union

I have a program that takes in one or more than one table names, from a list stored in a reference table and runs a SELECT query on it. so I retrieve the table names and insert it into the SELECT query in a loop.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table2 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table3 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table4 
    ) t1 
    WHERE 
    //where conditions
    AS name
```

this is the error

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 21:  AS name
```

query works if the AS clause is not present
              ^

Comment: What entity does you want to be referred to as `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"AS" clause can't be used in WHERE condition.

It's used to give an alias to table/view, column and to the query that return result-set, like sub-query & co-related query.

Like

```
SELECT
        MyTable.Column_A AS MyColumn --MyColumn is alias for Column_A
FROM    Table_A AS MyTable --Like wise MyTable is alias for Table_A
WHERE
        Column_B [Conditional Operator] [Input Value]
```

So, your query should be like

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM 
    (SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table2 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table3 
    UNION 
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table4 
    ) t1 
WHERE 
    t1.column [Conditional Operator] [Input Value]
```

Thanks!